# How to debug and edit multiple projects in the same visual studio solution

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, edit

I have a visual studio solution with two projects. Is it possible to debug one project and still be able to develop the other one?

Comment: I think that while debugging you can't edit classes, but you may edit js,cs,.. in case you are developing a web application

Comment: Is the second project referenced by the running one?

Comment: @Thomas no, they are independent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In Visual Studio go to `Tools | Options | Debugging | General`. (That's in 2015 Community Edition if this is version specific)
2. Uncheck `Enable Edit and continue` (at the end of the list)

Unfortunately, the window layouts of Visual Studio do not work well. Otherwise I would have suggested to

1. In development mode: save the window layout as "development" (in the `Window` menu)
2. Start debugging
3. In debug mode: save the window layout as "debug"
4. Load the "development" layout